# How to make a random object in this code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this script on the internet, and decided to put the standard asterisks, font ones. The font itself was connected via CSS. In the JS file I indicated what snowflakes are needed to fall. But if I put them, they fall in groups of three snowflakes in a line, but not randomly and not one by one:

```js
var snowmax=25;
var snowcolor=new Array("#AAAACC","#DDDDFF","#CCCCDD","#F3F3F3","#F0FFFF","#FFFFFF","#EFF5FF")
var snowtype=("Arial");
var snowletter=new Array("\u2744 \u2743 \u2742",);
var sinkspeed=0.5; 
var snowmaxsize=30;
var snowminsize=8;
var snowingzone=1;


var snow=new Array();
var marginbottom;
var marginright;
var timer;
var i_snow=0;
var x_mv=new Array();
var crds=new Array();
var lftrght=new Array();
var browserinfos=navigator.userAgent;
var ie5=document.all&&document.getElementById&&!browserinfos.match(/Opera/);
var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all;
var opera=browserinfos.match(/Opera/);
var browserok=ie5||ns6||opera;
function randommaker(range) {
    rand=Math.floor(range*Math.random());
    return rand;
}
function initsnow() {
    if (ie5 || opera) {
        marginbottom=document.body.clientHeight;
        marginright=document.body.clientWidth;
    }
    else if (ns6) {
        marginbottom=window.innerHeight;
        marginright=window.innerWidth;
    }
    var snowsizerange=snowmaxsize-snowminsize;
    for (i=0;i<=snowmax;i++) {
        crds[i]=0;
        lftrght[i]=Math.random()*15;
        x_mv[i]=0.03+Math.random()/10;
        snow[i]=document.getElementById("s"+i);
        snow[i].style.fontFamily=snowtype[randommaker(snowtype/length)];
        snow[i].size=randommaker(snowsizerange)+snowminsize;
        snow[i].style.fontSize=snow[i].size+"px";
        snow[i].style.color=snowcolor[randommaker(snowcolor.length)];
        snow[i].sink=sinkspeed*snow[i].size/5;
        if (snowingzone==1) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright-snow[i].size)}
        if (snowingzone==2) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)}
        if (snowingzone==3) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/4}
        if (snowingzone==4) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/2}
        snow[i].posy=randommaker(2*marginbottom-marginbottom-2*snow[i].size);
        snow[i].style.left=snow[i].posx+"px";
        snow[i].style.top=snow[i].posy+"px";
    }
    movesnow();
}
function movesnow() {
    for(i=0;i<=snowmax;i++) {
        crds[i]+=x_mv[i];
        snow[i].posy+=snow[i].sink;
        snow[i].style.left=snow[i].posx+lftrght[i]*Math.sin(crds[i])+"px";
        snow[i].style.top=snow[i].posy+"px";
        if (snow[i].posy>=marginbottom-2*snow[i].size || parseInt(snow[i].style.left)>(marginright-3*lftrght[i])) {
            if (snowingzone==1) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright-snow[i].size)}
            if (snowingzone==2) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)}
            if (snowingzone==3) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/4}
            if (snowingzone==4) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/2}
            snow[i].posy=0;
        }
    }
    var timer=setTimeout("movesnow()",50);
}
for (i=0;i<=snowmax;i++) {
    document.write("<span id='s"+i+"' style='position:absolute;top:-"+snowmaxsize+"px;'>"+snowletter+"</span>");
}
if (browserok) {
    window.onload=initsnow;
}
```

I'm not strong in JavaScript, and therefore my question: How to make it fall randomly, and one at a time? I am not able to find the solution myself.

Comment: I understand the requirement that it should be one-by-one, but what exactly do you mean with "fall randomly". Which aspect of the animation are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line which groups three snowfakes together is here:

```
var snowletter=new Array("\u2744 \u2743 \u2742",);
```

To just use one of those three by random, change this line to:

```
var snowletter="\u2744\u2743\u2742";
```

And also change the following line:

```
document.write("<span id='s"+i+"' style='position:absolute;top:-"+snowmaxsize+"px;'>"+snowletter+"</span>");
```

To:

```
document.write("<span id='s"+i
               +"' style='position:absolute;top:-"+snowmaxsize+"px;'>"
               + snowletter[Math.floor(Math.random()*snowletter.length)]
               +"</span>");
```

Here you see the result:

```js
var snowmax=25;
var snowcolor=new Array("#AAAACC","#DDDDFF","#CCCCDD","#F3F3F3","#F0FFFF","#FFFFFF","#EFF5FF")
var snowtype=("Arial");
var snowletter="\u2744\u2743\u2742";
var sinkspeed=0.5; 
var snowmaxsize=30;
var snowminsize=8;
var snowingzone=1;


var snow=new Array();
var marginbottom;
var marginright;
var timer;
var i_snow=0;
var x_mv=new Array();
var crds=new Array();
var lftrght=new Array();
var browserinfos=navigator.userAgent;
var ie5=document.all&&document.getElementById&&!browserinfos.match(/Opera/);
var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all;
var opera=browserinfos.match(/Opera/);
var browserok=ie5||ns6||opera;
function randommaker(range) {
    rand=Math.floor(range*Math.random());
    return rand;
}
function initsnow() {
    if (ie5 || opera) {
        marginbottom=document.body.clientHeight;
        marginright=document.body.clientWidth;
    }
    else if (ns6) {
        marginbottom=window.innerHeight;
        marginright=window.innerWidth;
    }
    var snowsizerange=snowmaxsize-snowminsize;
    for (i=0;i<=snowmax;i++) {
        crds[i]=0;
        lftrght[i]=Math.random()*15;
        x_mv[i]=0.03+Math.random()/10;
        snow[i]=document.getElementById("s"+i);
        snow[i].style.fontFamily=snowtype[randommaker(snowtype/length)];
        snow[i].size=randommaker(snowsizerange)+snowminsize;
        snow[i].style.fontSize=snow[i].size+"px";
        snow[i].style.color=snowcolor[randommaker(snowcolor.length)];
        snow[i].sink=sinkspeed*snow[i].size/5;
        if (snowingzone==1) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright-snow[i].size)}
        if (snowingzone==2) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)}
        if (snowingzone==3) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/4}
        if (snowingzone==4) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/2}
        snow[i].posy=randommaker(2*marginbottom-marginbottom-2*snow[i].size);
        snow[i].style.left=snow[i].posx+"px";
        snow[i].style.top=snow[i].posy+"px";
    }
    movesnow();
}
function movesnow() {
    for(i=0;i<=snowmax;i++) {
        crds[i]+=x_mv[i];
        snow[i].posy+=snow[i].sink;
        snow[i].style.left=snow[i].posx+lftrght[i]*Math.sin(crds[i])+"px";
        snow[i].style.top=snow[i].posy+"px";
        if (snow[i].posy>=marginbottom-2*snow[i].size || parseInt(snow[i].style.left)>(marginright-3*lftrght[i])) {
            if (snowingzone==1) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright-snow[i].size)}
            if (snowingzone==2) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)}
            if (snowingzone==3) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/4}
            if (snowingzone==4) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/2}
            snow[i].posy=0;
        }
    }
    var timer=setTimeout("movesnow()",50);
}
for (i=0;i<=snowmax;i++) {
   document.write("<span id='s"+i
                  +"' style='position:absolute;top:-"+snowmaxsize+"px;'>"
                  + snowletter[Math.floor(Math.random()*snowletter.length)]
                  +"</span>");

}
if (browserok) {
    window.onload=initsnow;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Upcoming holidays!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for one snowflake instead of the trio falling then isn't it just the snowletter declaration at the top that's giving you the the trio... change it to just one \u character and you get one...

```
var snowletter=new Array("\u2744 \u2743 \u2742",);
```

change to

```
var snowletter=new Array("\u2744");
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/m0aq57ng/

Answer (score 0):

Change your `snowletter` to array of snows: `new Array("\u2744", "\u2743", "\u2742")` and change how you pick snow randomly: `snowletter[Math.floor(Math.random()*snowletter.length)]`

Example code:

```js
var snowmax=25;
var snowcolor=new Array("#AAAACC","#DDDDFF","#CCCCDD","#F3F3F3","#F0FFFF","#FFFFFF","#EFF5FF")
var snowtype=("Arial");
var snowmax=25;
var snowcolor=new Array("#AAAACC","#DDDDFF","#CCCCDD","#F3F3F3","#F0FFFF","#FFFFFF","#EFF5FF")
var snowtype=("Arial");
var snowletter=new Array("\u2744", "\u2743", "\u2742");
var sinkspeed=0.5;
var snowmaxsize=30;
var snowminsize=8;
var snowingzone=1;

var snow=new Array();
var marginbottom;
var marginright;
var timer;
var i_snow=0;
var x_mv=new Array();
var crds=new Array();
var lftrght=new Array();
var browserinfos=navigator.userAgent;
var ie5=document.all&&document.getElementById&&!browserinfos.match(/Opera/);
var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all;
var opera=browserinfos.match(/Opera/);
var browserok=ie5||ns6||opera;

function randommaker(range) {
    rand=Math.floor(range*Math.random());
    return rand;
}

function initsnow() {
    if (ie5 || opera) {
        marginbottom=document.body.clientHeight;
        marginright=document.body.clientWidth;
    }
    else if (ns6) {
        marginbottom=window.innerHeight;
        marginright=window.innerWidth;
    }
    var snowsizerange=snowmaxsize-snowminsize;
    for (i=0;i<=snowmax;i++) {
        crds[i]=0;
        lftrght[i]=Math.random()*15;
        x_mv[i]=0.03+Math.random()/10;
        snow[i]=document.getElementById("s"+i);
        snow[i].style.fontFamily=snowtype[randommaker(snowtype/length)];
        snow[i].size=randommaker(snowsizerange)+snowminsize;
        snow[i].style.fontSize=snow[i].size+"px";
        snow[i].style.color=snowcolor[randommaker(snowcolor.length)];
        snow[i].sink=sinkspeed*snow[i].size/5;
        if (snowingzone==1) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright-snow[i].size)}
        if (snowingzone==2) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)}
        if (snowingzone==3) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/4}
        if (snowingzone==4) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/2}
        snow[i].posy=randommaker(2*marginbottom-marginbottom-2*snow[i].size);
        snow[i].style.left=snow[i].posx+"px";
        snow[i].style.top=snow[i].posy+"px";
    }
    movesnow();
}

function movesnow() {
    for(i=0;i<=snowmax;i++) {
        crds[i]+=x_mv[i];
        snow[i].posy+=snow[i].sink;
        snow[i].style.left=snow[i].posx+lftrght[i]*Math.sin(crds[i])+"px";
        snow[i].style.top=snow[i].posy+"px";
        if (snow[i].posy>=marginbottom-2*snow[i].size || parseInt(snow[i].style.left)>(marginright-3*lftrght[i])) {
            if (snowingzone==1) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright-snow[i].size)}
            if (snowingzone==2) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)}
            if (snowingzone==3) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/4}
            if (snowingzone==4) {snow[i].posx=randommaker(marginright/2-snow[i].size)+marginright/2}
            snow[i].posy=0;
        }
    }
    var timer=setTimeout("movesnow()",50);
}

for (i=0;i<=snowmax;i++) {
    document.write("<span id='s"+i+"' style='position:absolute;top:-"+snowmaxsize+"px;'>"+snowletter[Math.floor(Math.random()*snowletter.length)]+"</span>");
}

if (browserok) {
    window.onload=initsnow;
}
```